# Earth engine fill color by group

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like add a feature collection to my map, with a color indicating the group it belongs. Here I show you a screenshot of the results in QGIS I would like to arrive to in google earth engine:

[image]

For example, I would like to color the features by country. As an example, imagine I start with the 'states' feature collection:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");

var states = table.select('ADM0_NAME')

Map.addLayer(states)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display features in a collection with specific styling, use `FeatureCollection.style`.

```js
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");

var styled = table
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('style', {
      fillColor: feature.getNumber('ADM0_CODE').format('%06x')
    });
  })
  .style({
    styleProperty: 'style',
  });

Map.addLayer(styled);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/353d55f8f6e933c311baedded17d237f

However, you'll have to choose colors yourself — Earth Engine does not have a built-in method to pick colors based on distinct values of a property. In the above example, I've done it in a sloppy way by using the ADM0_CODE directly as a numeric color value, which will assign most countries shades of blue.

[image]

If you're interested in specific countries, you could hand write an `ee.Dictionary` that assigns colors to them. In this example, `'777777'` is the gray color that is used when no matching entry is present in the dictionary.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");

var colorTable = ee.Dictionary({
  'Spain': 'FF0000',
  'Germany': '00FF00',
  'Italy': '0000FF',
});

var styled = table
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('style', {
      fillColor: colorTable.get(feature.get('ADM0_NAME'), '777777')
    });
  })
  .style({
    styleProperty: 'style',
  });

Map.addLayer(styled);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c3231d141c97707e7b7685cfe7bb71e

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. It is a possible solution, but in my case I have 156 different groups, so I need a easier way to assign each group a color, is it possible? Thanks so much!

Comment: @FabioDanielTrinco There's no good way to do that that I know of. And with 156 items, any arbitrary assignment would be very likely to give you colors that were rather similar adjacent on the map.

Comment: That's partially true, take a look at the results obtained in QGIS. This is a detail of the zone. Its easy to view that all the clear blue items are part of the same group.

Answer (score 1):

did you try with image.paint() with the FeatureCollection as an argument? This is extremely powerful:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections_visualizing

This is just en example using the ADM0_CODE codes of three countries in order to pass these numbers to the palette:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");

var states_list = ['Italy','Germany','France'] //ADM0_CODE = 122 93 85

var states = table.filter(ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_NAME',states_list));

var empty = ee.Image().byte();

var palette = ['FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF'];

// Paint the interior of the polygons with different colors.

var fills = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: states,
  color: 'ADM0_CODE',
});

Map.addLayer(fills, {palette: palette,min: 85,max: 122}, 'colored countries');
```